# Add zero on a single digit string after "/" in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with the following format:

```
RMB-2018-726/12    
RMB-2019-27/16    
RMB-2019-160/21
RMB-2019-259/6
RMB-2019-433/2
```

Now what I need is to check the last digit or after the slash, if it is single digit add zero otherwise retain the value (for sorting purposes). I have already written a code using texttocolumn, len then merge columns, however it seems my solutions is long but it's working as per my needs.
For the sake of learning, I am wondering if there are other work around or more effective way to do this.

```
'Insert zero on single digit claim number
Dim myLastRow As Long
myLastRow = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Columns("J:M").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'Insert 4 new columns
'Column 1 = Batch Number; Column 2 = Claim Number; Column 3 = add zero on single digit; Column 4 = merge Column 1 + 3

Range("I2:I" & myLastRow).TextToColumns _
Destination:=Range("J2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:= _
        "/" 'TextToColumn the Batch Column = Column 1
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("L2:L" & myLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-1])=1,""0"","""")&RC[-1]" 'add zero on single digit only = Column 3
Range("M2:M" & myLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]&""/""&RC[-1]" 'combine the batch = Column 4

Range("M2:M" & myLastRow).Copy
Range("I2:I" & myLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False 'Where the original batch column
Columns("J:M").Delete
Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple pattern that I use all the time to update Range values super efficiently.

- Define target range
- Read the target range values into an array
- Modify the values
- Assign the array back to the target range

---

```
Sub FormatIDs()
    Dim data
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim BackSlashIndex As Long, r As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Set Target = .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    data = Target.Value

    For r = 1 To UBound(data)
        BackSlashIndex = InStrRev(data(r, 1), "/")
        If Len(data(r, 1)) - BackSlashIndex = 1 Then
            data(r, 1) = Left(data(r, 1), Len(data(r, 1)) - 1) & "0" & Right(data(r, 1), 1)
        End If
    Next

    Target.Value = data
End Sub
```

Comment: The above solution is way better and a lot more faster. Thank you for sharing your solution.

Comment: Referring on the sample data, the second data (RMB-2019-27/16 ) has double digit instead of three digit before the slash. How should be added in the script to add zero if the number (before the slash) is just two or single digit (I want a default 3 digit to effectively sort the data). Your code is interesting and I will try to dissect it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    colLatter = "A"
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, colLatter).End(xlUp).Row
        valArr = ws.Range(colLatter & "1:" & colLatter & LastRow).Value
        For i = LBound(valArr) To UBound(valArr)
            If valArr(i, 1) <> "" Then
                sStr = Split(valArr(i, 1), "/")
                valArr(i, 1) = sStr(0) & "/" & Format(sStr(1), "00")
            End If
        Next i
        ws.Range(colLatter & "1").Resize(UBound(valArr), 1) = valArr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As an FYI, this can be done without vba:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1))&IF(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-2,1)="/",RIGHT(A1,2),"0"&RIGHT(A1,1))
```

Or, adding a zero if needed before the slash as well (as requested in a comment on another answer):

```
=LEFT(A1,9)&IF(MID(A1,13,1)="/",MID(A1,10,4),"0"&MID(A1,10,3))&IF(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-2,1)="/",RIGHT(A1,2),"0"&RIGHT(A1,1))
```

Note than any more complications (the possibility of a single digit before the slash for example) and this will quickly become unwieldy, so for extensibility vba is definitely the better option.